# How to translate Matlab's dot operators into R?

Tags: r, matlab

Matlab has a set of dot operators, such as `.*`, `./`, `.^`. Each of these operators consists of a dot and a normal algebraic operator. 
I would like to translate these into R:

```
col = round(r0 + (j/k) * lambda .* cos(pi/6))+1;
ro    = 700 - round(s0 - (j/k) * sin(phi)./cos(pi/6))
col = min(col):1:max(col)
ro    = min(ro):1:max(ro)
```

Please help

Comment: In  R, unlike Matlab, all operations are element-wise.

Comment: You may also like this MATLAB/R comparison sheet: http://www.math.umaine.edu/~hiebeler/comp/matlabR.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows insufficient effort to learn the basics of R

Comment: In addition to @RichieCotton 's link, here's one which offers multiple language "Rosetta" pages  http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @CarlWitthoft links now added to the info page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert your lines of code to characters and use gsub

```
a <- "col = round(r0 + (j/k) * lambda .* cos(pi/6))+1;"
a <- gsub("\\.","",a)
```

which you could wrap in a function.

So, here's a function to do it,

```
DotOut  <- function(x) {
 gsub("\\.","",x)
}
```

You could then use this function in one of the apply functions.

Comment: agree with your edits @docendo and of course your comments, thanks.

Comment: Which will lead to disaster every time there's a floating-point number with a dot in it.

Comment: the OP should be aware of this...

Comment: Even so, learning to write robust code is its own reward :-) . Try writing a regex which rejects strings of the form `[0-9][.][0-9]` :-) to avoid this risk.

Comment: Any other hints @Carl ?

Comment: nahhh... I'll leave it as a homework exercise.

Comment: @Carl OK.  Worked out how to do it but I have a problem: the sample regex you gave me, [0-9][.][0-9] takes out the dot AND the numerals either side of it.  What is the regex for taking out the dot but leaving the numerals that would have been on either side of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67580/discussion-between-carl-witthoft-and-user1945827).

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB, the dot operators `.*`, `./`, `.^` denote element-wise operators, compared to the matrix operations `*` (matrix multiplication), `/` (solve equation system xA=B for x), `^` (A*A...*A).

In R, the operators `*`, `/`, `^` denote element-wise operations, while you use `%*%` for matrix multiplication.